# Python 3 tkinter: focus_force on messagebox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm running python 3 code in background which should show a popup window in some situations. I'm using tkinter for this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def popup(message, title=None):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    messagebox.showinfo(title, message, parent=root)
    root.destroy()

popup('foo')
```

The ok-button in this infobox should get the focus automatically when popping up. Sadly I'm not able to do this. I tried `root.focus()`, but it does not help. Any ideas how to solve that? TIA

BTW: The code should be platform independent (Linux and Windows).

Edit:
Maybe I missunderstood the focus keyword and I should clarify my question:

```py
root = tk.Tk()
root.focus_force()
root.wait_window()
```

When calling the code above the root window is active, even if I worked in e.g. the browser before. Is this also possible for `messagebox.showinfo`? Adding `root.focus_force()` in the popup function does not help.

Is this even possible? Or is it necessary to create my own root window? I really like the appearance of the messagebox with the icon.

Edit 2:
Here is a video: https://filebin.net/no195o9rjy3qq5c4/focus.mp4
The editor is the active window, even after the popup was shown.
In Linux I it works as expected.

Comment: Read up on [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Comment: Are you using MacOs or Windows? I am using windows, and the button is already in focus when the window opens up. If you are using Mac, then see my answer.

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/7414759)
and [When to use the Toplevel Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm)

Comment: Why would you expect anything done to `root` to have any effect on the messagebox?  Those are two separate windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`default`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm) argument in the `messagebox` function.

> default constant
>
> Which button to make default: ABORT, RETRY, IGNORE, OK, CANCEL, YES, or NO (the constants are defined in the tkMessageBox module).

So, here is an example to highlight the "ok" button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def popup(message, title=None):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo(title, message, parent=root, default = "ok")

    root.destroy()

popup('foo')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The ok button has the focus, but not the messagebox window. I clarified my question a bit.

Comment: @Lugino What do you mean by _The ok button has the focus, but not the messagebox window_?  Include in your questions a video of the behavior. Thanks!

Comment: When I run it on windows, the window has all the focus.

Comment: @Lugino I edited my code, try to run the code now, and see if it works.